# jquery cross browser solution

Tags: jquery

What is the jQuery equivalent to the following:

```
function stopEvent(evt) {
if (window.event) window.event.cancelBubble = true;
else evt.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery [Event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) implements a [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method which is a cross-browser way to prevent events from bubbling up the DOM tree. Example:

```
// when an anchor with id of someElement gets clicked
$("#someElement").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Bear in mind, `return false` has the same effect as calling both `e.preventDefault()` *and* `e.stopPropagation()`.